# i want to clip a image only if the width is bigger then the container

Tags: css

I am making a site for a client of mine. The problem that is that all the pictures are not the same. I have a height of 500px and a width of 800px. now i want the height to always be full so i have img{ height:100%; width:auto;} but now what I want is if the width is bigger that it clips the image so that the middle of the picture is always vissible. But I only wanted it to be clipped when the width is smaller then 800px.

Thanks for all the answers in advence.

Comment: realy weird it wanted to delete my hi guys so i will do it this way

Comment: HI GUYS I AM TRUSTING YOU WITH MY LIFE

Comment: What who is what where ..? To get decent help provide sections of your code that are affected to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the evrybody, i have found the answer.

this is the css that i am using:

```
.custom-page-thumbnail-container{
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 350px;
}
.custom-page-thumbnail-container img{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 6px double #186F38;
    margin-left: -100%;
    margin-right:-100%;}
```

it works realy well. dont ask me why this works but it does

Answer (score 0):

Using the CSS `background-size` property, you can scale proportionally and have the excess clipped automatically.

You can achieve this by doing something like this in your CSS:

```
.imgFill
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

In your HTML you could use it like this:

```
<div class="imgFill" style="background-image:url(path/to/image_01.jpg)"></div>
```

Comment: this would work but the problem is that it is a normal image and not a background. this image the database of wordpress. so i cant use it as a background. thanks for the reply anyway :D

Comment: @LeondenBoer :: I'm sure you can refer to it as a "background", the result will be the same - an image being displayed, no matter how. If the image is in the database as "blob" or base64 encoded binary, you can use it by either converting the blob to base64, or using the base64 directly, with the mime-type explicitly specified like this: `url(data:image/jpeg;base64,....)`

Comment: You can also achieve proportionally scaled and cropped images by embedding it inside SVG; however, if you cannot think outside the proverbial box there's nothing anyone can do for you, because such a person will just shoot down any helpful comment others provide, including other methods like using JavaScript together with the methods mentioned above, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/1200/300" alt="" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="" />
</div>
```